# Microsoft 365 Developer Program have conditional access

Tags: microsoft365

I have subscribed to Microsoft 365 Developer Program to try few features.

I can login to the MS 365 Dev admin, but if I want to login with my tennant admin account, I got error :

> You don't have access to this Your sign-in was successful but you
>
> don't have permission to access this resource.
>
>  Error Code: 53003

Error code 53003 seem related to conditionnal access. I never was able to login, so I doesn't activate conditional access.

How can I connect to my tennant admin center ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can’t sign in to the Microsoft 365 Developer Program with your sandbox subscription administrator ID. Please sign in with your Developer Program account (the account you used to join). For details, see the FAQ.